# Getting null values while reading application.yaml file in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, microservices

I am trying to fetch the data from my application.yaml file which contain profile details, into variables

application.yaml file contents

```
spring.profiles.active: dev
---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: dev

application.id : dev-app
my.server : localhost:8080
---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: uat

application.id : uat-app
my.server : localhost:8081
```

App.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

@Value("${application.id}")
private String applicationId;

@Value("${my.server}")
private String server;

 public static void main(String args[]) {

    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

    App app = new App();
    app.display();

}

public void display(){
   System.out.println("Application Id : "+ applicationId);
   System.out.println("Server : "+ server);
}

}
```

Output:

```
2022-06-08 19:38:29 main INFO  App:640 - The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2022-06-08 19:38:30 main INFO  App:61 - Started App in 2.266 seconds (JVM running for 3.345)
Application Id : null
Server : null
```

Could you please help me to understand why it is not picking the values from yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

in your yml, what you have is formatted in a ".properties' file format, you need to format your property to yml format. So, your yml file should be in the format (something like this):

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  config:
    activate:
  onProfile: dev

application:
  id : dev-app
```

etc...

Comment: YAML supports the dot format and even mixed format. Furthermore, since Boot 2 all properties should be kebab-case (`on-profile` rather than `onProfile`).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- is saying correct here, any idea what's wrong in my code?